# What is the difference between the core, vendor and site locations in Perl?

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan, cpanm

I recently ran into some trouble installing some modules and discovered to my surprise that many of the modules that had been installed, have duplicated installations and versions. Trying to track where stuff goes in a standard (if there is such a thing) installation using `cpanm`, I found the following results very confusing.

The reports show these locations:

- Using `cpan -V`:

```sh
# cpan -V

/usr/bin/cpan script version 1.672, CPAN.pm version 2.22
--------------------------------------------------
Checking install dirs...
Checking core
        + /usr/share/perl5/5.26
        + /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
Checking vendor
        + /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26
        + /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
Checking site
        + /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26
        + /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
Checking PERL5LIB
        no directories for PERL5LIB
Checking PERLLIB
        no directories for PERLLIB
```

- Using `perl -V:.*site.*`:

```sh
# perl -V:.*site.* |column -t -s "=" |sort -d -i -k 1.22

d_sitearch           'define';
usesitecustomize     'undef';
siteprefix           '/usr/local';
siteprefixexp        '/usr/local';
installsitebin       '/usr/local/bin';
installsitescript    '/usr/local/bin';
sitebin              '/usr/local/bin';
sitebinexp           '/usr/local/bin';
sitescript           '/usr/local/bin';
sitescriptexp        '/usr/local/bin';
installsitearch      '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
sitearch             '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
sitearchexp          '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
installsitehtml1dir  '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html1';
sitehtml1dir         '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html1';
sitehtml1direxp      '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html1';
installsitehtml3dir  '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html3';
sitehtml3dir         '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html3';
sitehtml3direxp      '/usr/local/share/doc/perl/html/html3';
installsiteman1dir   '/usr/local/share/man/man1';
siteman1dir          '/usr/local/share/man/man1';
siteman1direxp       '/usr/local/share/man/man1';
installsiteman3dir   '/usr/local/share/man/man3';
siteman3dir          '/usr/local/share/man/man3';
siteman3direxp       '/usr/local/share/man/man3';
installsitelib       '/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26';
sitelib              '/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26';
sitelib_stem         '/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26';
sitelibexp           '/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26';
```

- Using `@INC`:

```sh
# perl -e 'print join("\n",@INC,"")'

/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26
/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads
/usr/share/perl5/5.26
```

The result is that `cpan-outdated -p --verbose` show a completely different (and shorter) list of outdated modules than what `cpan -lO` does. Needless to say, modules are installed all over the place and I don't see how to understand if there is a default install location and where it goes, or *should* go.

---

**QUESTION**:

1. So what is the difference between the `core`, `vendor` and `site` *type* of paths?
2. Why are there 2 paths in each type?

Comment: Answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379902/589924)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! (I would never have found it under that question.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best reference for these install locations is probably the [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#make-install) documentation for where it installs things. In essence:

- **`core`** (also known as *privlib*) - is where core modules that are installed with Perl goes. On Perls older than 5.12, updates to dual-life modules also need to be installed here over the core versions instead of into site or vendor lib, because privlib came first in `@INC` before 5.12. This is especially dangerous in a system Perl where the files in privlib are usually managed by a package manager.
- **`vendor`** - is where a distribution vendor may install modules to. This is usually where system package managers install non-core modules to.
- **`site`** - is where CPAN clients install modules to when invoked directly, barring unusual configuration like for dual-life modules as mentioned above.

(Dual-life modules are core modules which are also available separately on CPAN, which means that you can install an updated version.)

Each of these lib locations have an **`arch`** variant, which is where distributions with build-specific output files are installed to. Pure-perl distributions with no dynamic configuration are installed into the standard architecture-agnostic directory, and can usually run unmodified in other installations of Perl and architectures provided their requirements are still satisfied (though it's not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing). *Distributions with any compiled XS modules or that generate modules dynamically in the build process are installed into the `arch` directory and are not safe to use from another Perl.*

All of these locations are configured when the Perl is built and can be discovered using the `perl -V` option as you showed. They also each have accompanying `script` and `bin` directories (which are usually the same) and directories for manpages.

As to the discrepancy of `cpan-outdated` - this tool (like many tools using [ExtUtils::Installed](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::Installed)) is restricted to finding modules that have *packlists*, which are included when installing a module using a CPAN client, but not with core modules and they are generally stripped from vendor packages. So most likely `cpan-outdated` will only discover modules in *sitelib*, but this is usually all you need to find. I'm not sure what mechanism the cpan command uses.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to *ikegami*'s SO link, I have since done some source browsing, where we can find a lot of info about this. To get the more specific locations:

```
# perl -V:'install(privlib|archlib|vendorlib|vendorarch|sitelib|sitearch)' |column -t -s "="

installarchlib     '/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
installprivlib     '/usr/share/perl5/5.26';
installsitearch    '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
installsitelib     '/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26';
installvendorarch  '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads';
installvendorlib   '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26';
```

Then for the meaning of those, we can look (in the perl sources) in the file: `./Porting/Glossary`:

```
installarchlib    '- is the same for modules with arch- or build-dependent components.'
installprivlib    '- contains the "pure Perl" modules that came with Perl.'
installsitearch   '- is the same for modules with arch- or build-dependent components.'
installsitelib    '- contains the "pure Perl" modules installed by you.'
installvendorarch '- is the same for modules with arch- or build-dependent components.'
installvendorlib  '- contains the "pure Perl" modules installed by your distro.'
```

with the additional interesting note about the *installstyle* option:

> `installstyle (installstyle.U):`
>
> This variable describes the **style** of the perl installation. This
>   is intended to be useful for tools that need to manipulate entire perl
>   distributions. Perl itself doesn't use this to find its libraries --
>   the library directories are stored directly in Config.pm. Currently,
>   there are only two styles:  **`lib`** and **`lib/perl5`**. The default
>   library locations (e.g. privlib, sitelib) are either `$prefix/lib` or
>   `$prefix/lib/perl5`. The former is useful if **$prefix** is a
>   directory dedicated to perl (e.g. /opt/perl), while the latter is
>   useful if $prefix is shared by many packages, e.g. if
>   `$prefix=/usr/local`.
>
> Unfortunately, while this "style" variable is used to set defaults for
>   all three directory hierarchies (core, vendor, and site), there is no
>   guarantee that the same style is actually appropriate for all those
>   directories.  For example, $prefix might be /opt/perl, but
>   `$siteprefix` might be /usr/local. (Perhaps, in retrospect, the "lib"
>   style should never have been supported, but it did seem like a nice
>   idea at the time.)
>
> The situation is even less clear for tools such as MakeMaker that can
>   be used to install additional modules into non-standard places.  For
>   example, if a user intends to install a module into a private
>   directory (perhaps by setting PREFIX on the Makefile.PL command line),
>   then there is no reason to assume that the Configure-time
>   $installstyle setting will be relevant for that PREFIX.
>
> This may later be extended to include other information, so be careful
>   with pattern-matching on the results.
>
> For compatibility with perl5.005 and earlier, the default setting is
>   based on whether or not $prefix contains the string "perl".

All the gritty details can then be found in the `INSTALLATION` file, under the `Installation Directories` heading.

- `Directories for the perl distribution`:
  By default, Configure will use the following directories (5.28.1):

  ```
      Configure variable  Default value
      $prefixexp          /usr/local
      $binexp             $prefixexp/bin
      $scriptdirexp       $prefixexp/bin
      $privlibexp         $prefixexp/lib/perl5/$version
      $archlibexp         $prefixexp/lib/perl5/$version/$archname
  ```
- `Directories for site-specific add-on files`:

  ```
     Configure        Default
     variable          value
   $siteprefixexp    $prefixexp
   $sitebinexp       $siteprefixexp/bin
   $sitescriptexp    $siteprefixexp/bin
   $sitelibexp       $siteprefixexp/lib/perl5/site_perl/$version
   $sitearchexp      $siteprefixexp/lib/perl5/site_perl/$version/$archname
  ```
- `Directories for vendor-supplied add-on files`:

  If are building a binary distribution of perl for distribution, Configure
  can optionally set up the following directories for you to use to 
  distribute add-on modules.

  ```
     Configure          Default
     variable            value
   $vendorprefixexp    (none)

   (The next ones are set only if vendorprefix is set.)

   $vendorbinexp       $vendorprefixexp/bin
   $vendorscriptexp    $vendorprefixexp/bin
   $vendorlibexp       $vendorprefixexp/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/$version
   $vendorarchexp      $vendorprefixexp/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/$version/$archname
  ```
- `otherlibdirs`:
  As a final catch-all, Configure also offers an `$otherlibdirs` variable. 
  This variable contains a colon-separated list of additional directories 
  to add to **@INC**. By default, it will be empty.
- `APPLLIB_EXP`:
  There is one other way of adding paths to @INC at perl build 
  time, and that is by setting the APPLLIB_EXP C pre-processor 
  token. The directories defined by APPLLIB_EXP get added to 
  @INC **first**, ahead of any others.
  `sh Configure -Accflags='-DAPPLLIB_EXP=\"/usr/libperl\"'`