# Perl: How to deal with a duplicated modules installation?

Tags: strawberry-perl, perl, cpanm

I'm new with Perl and stumbled on a doubled modules installation.

I made a fresh installation of [Strawbery Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) on `Windows 10`. After that, I tried to update all modules at once by using a command proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727795/how-do-i-update-all-my-cpan-modules-to-their-latest-versions); :

```
cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
```

Unfortunately, it appeared that probably the updates were installed on another location:

```
whichpm -a Mojolicious
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm
C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm


whichpm -v Mojolicious
whichpm: WARNING: DUPLICATE module files found for 'Mojolicious':
  C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm
Mojolicious     8.22    (non-core)      C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm
```

How to deal whit that case?

How to prevent such cases in further updates?

```
perl -wE "say for @INC"

C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/Strawberry/perl/lib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is working as expected.

---

There are three sets of installation locations: core, vendor and site.

The vendor directories are usually used by the package managers of linux distros, but it appears that Strawberry Perl includes a number of non-core modules in its distribution (including Mojolicious) and it places these in the vendor directories. **This is proper.**<sup>[1]</sup>

The site directories are used for user-installed modules. So your upgraded Mojolicious was installed into the site directories. **This is proper.**

(More on the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470382/589924).)

This is not a problem because the site directories are placed before the vendor directories in `@INC`, so the user-installed version of a module is found before the vendor-installed version.

---

1. Using the site directories would probably also have been fine since Strawberry Perl doesn't provide a way of managing the distributions it bundles. But using the vendor directories is sure to be safe.